# Llama index embeddings not generated: "Embeddings have been explicitly disabled. Using MockEmbedding."

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, llama-index, retrieval-augmented-generation

I'm learning how to use LlamaIndex for retrieval augmented generation (RAG), i.e. Making chatbots that can answer questions based on documents containing a mixture of text, tables, images, etc. I'm trying to  follow a tutorial running this [notebook](https://github.com/sudarshan-koirala/youtube-stuffs/blob/main/llamaindex/llamaindex_Semi_Structured_RAG.ipynb) in Colab. When running this block:

```
import os
import pickle

raw_nodes_2021 = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(docs_2021)
pickle.dump(raw_nodes_2021, open("2021_nodes.pkl", "wb"))
```

it prints the following output:

```
Embeddings have been explicitly disabled. Using MockEmbedding.
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

As a result, the `node_mappings_2021` variable is an empty dict. What is missing? How can I enable Embeddings?

EDIT: To reproduce the error run this [notebook in Colab](https://github.com/sudarshan-koirala/youtube-stuffs/blob/main/llamaindex/llamaindex_Semi_Structured_RAG.ipynb)

Comment: `node_parser` is not defined.  what is this ?

Comment: @D.L node_parser is defined in a previous block in the notebook as follows: """"from llama_index.node_parser import (
    UnstructuredElementNodeParser,
)

node_parser = UnstructuredElementNodeParser()"""

Comment: add it to the code so that it is clear. the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The straightforward way to reproduce the error is to open the notebook in colab, that's why I left the [link](https://github.com/sudarshan-koirala/youtube-stuffs/blob/main/llamaindex/llamaindex_Semi_Structured_RAG.ipynb)